# meaning of "get on" in dictionary

Tags: phrasal-verbs

One of the meanings of "get on" is to mount a car or to mount a vehicle or to mount etc. But there is not this meaning in the Longman dictionary and Oxford dictionary. Why?

Comment: Good question. Maybe these dictionaries don't consider "get on" to be an idiomatic expression - see definition 4.1 of "get", which is what you're looking for, I think https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/get - though I could see thinking that "to get on the bus" or "to get on the train" sound idiomatic, as you wouldn't literally get *on top of* them.

Comment: Unless someone from Longman or OUP wants to comment, I don't think this can be answered, only speculated upon.

Comment: But definition 4.1 of "get" in Oxford  is about "get into", not "get on"

Comment: @Darman see the "+More example sentences" - there are other prepositional phrases used there too, e.g. ‘Dreams were destroyed when a person decided to *get behind* the wheel after drinking.’

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries vary based on whether the lexicographer considers a particular phrase a special case or not. In some dictionaries, they consider "**get on**" a special case, a phrasal verb. In others, they consider it a normal usage of one of the senses of *get* that they list.

It's used as readily in British as American English, it's just dictionaries with different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

It's in Cambridge

> get on (sth)
>
> phrasal verb with get
>
> present participle getting
>   past tense got
>   past participle got or (USA) usually gotten ​
>
> A2 to go onto a bus, train, aircraft, or boat:
>
> I think we got on the wrong bus.
>   Pay the driver as you get on.
>   Show your boarding pass as you get on.
>   When he heard the news, Simon got on the next train to London.
>   The old
>   woman had difficulty getting on to the bus.
>   A lot of people usually
>   get on the train at Cambridge.

[Get on (sth)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-on-sth)

Comment: Yes, thank you. But this is odd for me that there is not in those dictionaries. Is it true that this meaning of "get on" is not in America but in English?

Comment: @Darman *Get on* has a specific entry in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get%20on).

Comment: @JasonBassford the meanings of "get on" in Merriam-Webster are not the ones Darman is looking for. And Darman - this meaning of "get on" is definitely used in American English.

Comment: @Mixolydian I was pointing out that *get on* is listed as separate entry in the dictionary, I wasn't talking about the specific meaning. In fact, I was partially responding to your own comment that said "Maybe these dictionaries don't consider 'get on' to be an idiomatic expression." That it is listed in MW at all, means that MW does consider it to be an idiomatic expression. But "get on" in the specific sense in the question is not—because it means nothing more or less than what the individual words mean. Which is already defined *by* the combination of those two words.

Comment: @JasonBassford got it - yes, I misspoke in saying that 'get on' is not considered to be an idiomatic expression (or phrasal verb) by these dictionaries - I meant only that this specific meaning of 'get on' is not. Other meanings of 'get on' like 'get along' do in fact have their own definitions.